# How to check if values of a numeric 2D PHP array are in 'incereasing' , 'descending' , or 'mixed' order?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am looking for a method to check if values of a numeric 2D PHP array are in

**incereasing** ,
**descending** ,
or 
**mixed** order.

Example:

```
array( 1, 2, 3, 4 ) // This is an incereasing numeric array
array( 4, 3, 2, 1 ) // This is a descending numeric array
array( 1, 3, 2, 4 ) // This is a mixed numeric array
```

How could I check it? ( i am looking for a fast method, it needs to run qickly )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, if you are looking for quick solution (i.e. works quick), you'll have to work with your data array like:

```
function getOrder($rgData)
{
   if(!count($rgData) || count($rgData)==1)
   {
      return null;
   }
   $sCurrent = (string)array_shift($rgData);
   $iOrder   = current($rgData)>$sCurrent?1:-1;
   foreach($rgData as $mValue)
   {
      if(($sCurrent>(string)$mValue && $iOrder== 1) ||
         ($sCurrent<(string)$mValue && $iOrder==-1))
      {
         return 0;
      }
      $sCurrent = (string)$mValue;
   }
   return $iOrder;
}
```

this will return 1,0 and -1 for corresponding ascending, mixed and descending order. Note, that all values will be treated and compared as strings. This method is more useful since it have `O(N)` complexity (at worst case) while using `sort()` function will result in `O(N log(N))` complexity (at best case)

Comment: This is a really fast, and smooth way, works really great! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your variable is called `$array` this might start in the right direction:

```
$tempArray=sort($array);
if($array==$tempArray)
{
    // Array is in acsending order
}

$tempArray=arsort($array);
if($array==$tempArray)
{
    // Array is in desending order
}
```

If neither of these match, it's mixed.

Edit: Thanks to  Alma Do Mundo, Corrected code.

Comment: `sort` and it's company will **not** return array, it return bool 1/0 (and modify array in passed argument), so your comparison is not valid

Comment: It's not a "fast" method as requested though

Comment: @Fluffeh now it's a quick solution, but quick means 'quick to write', not 'quick to process' :p `sort()` will result at best in `O(N log(N))` complexity while all we need is `O(N)` In addition, memory complexity for `sort()` variant is `O(3N)` since you're storing original data 3 times